# Rspec Recaptcha

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, recaptcha

I am trying to expect authentication to fail even though email and password are correct but user did not check the captcha box. How do I force :verify_captcha or its wrapper method :check_captcha to return false in rspec?

```
context "when captcha box is not checked" do
  it "should not be able to log in even though email and password is correct" do
    # Recaptcha.configuration.skip_verify_env.delete('test')
    # allow(controller).to receive(:check_captcha).and_return(false)

    params = { :user => { :email => @email, :password => @password } }
    post 'create', params
    expect(response.code).to eq("302")
  end
end
```

I have tried either of the commented lines to force captcha to not be checked. Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you're expecting it to succeed.

Comment: hey @SergioTulentsev, thanks for spotting. I updated my question. I want it to fail but its succeeding now.

Comment: Still you're expecting it to succeed (the http 200 code) :)

Comment: whoops :sweat_smile: